# Storing checkbox values in sessions and then re-selecting check boxes checked when they came back to add some more

Tags: php, checkbox

I am trying to pass my checkbox values through a session variable if the user goes back by clicking  add more books link. I want to show them previously selected check boxes are checked. I tried in chklist.php page

```
if(isset($_SESSION['pro'])){ 
echo  $_SESSION['pro'];}
```

shows values like 1_2_5 which are  present in session array.
Here is my html code of checkboxes. I have about 24 checkboxes with the same name as product[].

```
<name="product[]"  type="checkbox" value="1" alt="1607.00" />
<name="product[]"  type="checkbox" value="2" alt="1607.00" />
```

and so on
Here I am setting my session after POST of checkboxes .

```
$_SESSION['pro'] = implode('_', $_POST['product']);
```

in nextpage chkout.php.
How to make previously selected  checkboxes are checked when user came back to firstpage(chklist.php) by clicking  ADD MORE BOOKS link present in chkout.php, can any body write the code what i need add to my html.

Comment: I do not see your code o_o

Comment: <input  name="product[]"  type="checkbox" value="1" alt="1607.00" /><input  name="product[]"  type="checkbox" value="2" alt="180.00" />//and so on upto 24 checkboxes, and thanks for you fast response this is my first post in stack overflow

Comment: product is an array, do $_SESSION['checks'] = $_POST['product']; and do print it (with var_dump or print_r) in the first page, you will see all the checkbox checked i think

Comment: I tried print_r($_SESSION['checks']); It is showing Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 13 [2] => 14 ) but checkboxes are not checked can you please tell me what i need to write to make checkboxes checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put products array into session then access it as an array.

When setting:

```
$_SESSION["products"] = $_POST["product"];
```

When listing products, you should check the values from session:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
    echo '<name="product[]"  type="checkbox" value="'.$i.'" alt="1607.00"';
    if(in_array($i, $_SESSION["products"])) echo ' checked="checked" ';
    echo ' />';
}
```

This is the basic idea and example code.

**--UPDATE--**

According to your comments:

Inside the form, we will print products as follow:

```
<?php
session_start();
$session_products = array();
if(array_key_exists("products", $_SESSION)) 
{
  if($_SESSION["products"] != null)
  {
    $session_products = $_SESSION["products"];
  }
}

<form method="post" action="newtest.php"> 
    <input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if(in_array("1", $session_products)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> alt="1607.00" /> 
    <input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="2" <?php if(in_array("2", $session_products)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  alt="1848.00" /> 
    <input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="3" <?php if(in_array("3", $session_products])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  alt="180.00" /> 
    <input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="4" <?php if(in_array("4", $session_products)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  alt="650.00" />
    and so on upto 24 ...
</form>
```

Inside the code where the form values are posted, we will put these values into session:

```
<?php 
include("config.php"); 
session_start(); 

if(isset($_POST))
{ 
    $_SESSION["products"] = $_POST["product"];
}
?>
```

Comment: I copied your code here<?php
include("config.php");
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['products'])){ 
for($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
    echo '<name="product[]"  type="checkbox" value="'.$i.'" alt="1607.00"';
    if(in_array($i, $_SESSION["products"])) echo ' checked="checked" ';
    echo ' />';}
}?>

Comment: This is my form
 <form method="post" action="newtest.php">
<input  name="product[]"  type="checkbox" value="1" alt="1607.00" />   
<input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="2" alt="1848.00" /> 
<input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="3" alt="180.00" />  
 <input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="4" alt="650.00" />and so on upto 24
</form>
Can you please tell me where i need to put yore code or any other thing can i do with input fields

Comment: @ isa   as you said i made changes to the form,

Comment: @ isa   as you said i made changes to the form,and Inside the code where the form values are posted, i put that session code now its working fine when i select the check boxes and came back to front page(the pafe form present) by clicking the link <a href="test.php" ><input type="button"  name="button" value="ADD MORE BOOK'S " ></a>  But ,when i open the page test.php (The page form present) for the first time it is showing Notice: Undefined index: products ,Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  please help me.

Comment: @Nag, please add session_start() command in test.php . Check the code above, i have updated it.

Comment: Now it is working fine except this Notice: Undefined index: products in C:\xampp\htdocs\newbooklist\test.php on line 3,

Comment: @Nag, please change $_SESSION[] == null to isset($_SESSION["products"]). Please see the update above.

Comment: if i change to $session_products = (isset($_SESSION["products"])) ? array() : $_SESSION["products"];  it is showing error like   Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\newbooklist\test.php on line 126
alt="1848.00" />

Comment: it is working fine with $session_products = ($_SESSION["products"] == null) ? array() : $_SESSION["products"];                      only it is showing  Notice: Undefined index: products in C:\xampp\htdocs\newbooklist\test.php on line 3, each time i close and open the browser(when i open the browser for the first time) please replay me

Comment: Thanks a lot isa :-) Now everything is working fine with no errors, actually am using the following link for ADD MORE BOOks          <a href="test.php" ><input type="button" style="margin-left: 214px;" name="button" value="ADD MORE BOOK'S " class="ph-button ph-btn-green fm-submit"></a>, Can you please tell me why this link is not redirecting to test.php  in Explorer 11 for Windows 7

Comment: Do not use input tag inside a tag. You can give the link as: <a href="test.php">ADD MORE BOOKS</a> If this is a submit button of a form, then omit the a tag and just use <input> tag. If you want to make the link look like a button, use css. google "css buttons" and this will give you some hints.