# how to bind multiple checkbox in different session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some data with check boxes. Now I want, when any one click on check boxes then all data of checked should be bind in session and should go on next page. And again if any one click on check boxes then new clicked data should be in session. But old data should not delete. I tried but not working, any thing. Please help.

```
                            <form  name="reservation_form" class="reservation-form mb-0" action="second.php" method="post" novalidate>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group mb-15">
              <input name="name1" class="form-control required " type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" aria-required="true">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group mb-15">
              <input name="email1" class="form-control required " type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" aria-required="true">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group mb-15">
              <input name="phone1" class="form-control required " type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone" aria-required="true">
            </div>
          </div>
     <?php
            $query1=mysql_query("select * from lab_location_package_rel where city_id='$selectcity1' AND area_id='$selectarea1' AND lab_id='$selectlab1'") or die (mysql_error());          
             while($value = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
                 $mrp=$value['mrp'];
                 $opp=$value['offer_price_perc'];
                 $package_id=$value['package_id'];

                 $per=$mrp*$opp/100;
                 $total=$mrp-$per;

             $query2=mysql_query("select * from package_master where id='$package_id'") or die (mysql_error());
             $value2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
             ?>     
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="name[]" />
                            <label for="checkbox">
                               <b>Package Name:</b> <?php echo $value2['package_title']; ?> <br>
                               <b>MRP:</b>  <strike><?php echo $value['mrp']; ?>  </strike><br>
                               <b>Offer Price:</b>  <?php echo $total; ?>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-right action-buttons">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">View Details</a>
                       </div>
                    </li>
              <?php } ?>     

                </ul>
            </div>
       <input type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-warning" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

In given code, when any one fill all fields and click check boxes-

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="name[]" />
                        <label for="checkbox">
                           <b>Package Name:</b> <?php echo $value2['package_title']; ?> <br>
                           <b>MRP:</b>  <strike><?php echo $value['mrp']; ?>  </strike><br>
                           <b>Offer Price:</b>  <?php echo $total; ?>
                        </label>
```

then all filled fields and Package Name, MRP, Offer Price (these name will be selected for each checkbox) should be bind in session.

Comment: Maybe helpful to you => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561922/storing-checkbox-values-in-sessions-and-then-re-selecting-check-boxes-checked-wh

Comment: Thank you for reply...But I tried it from 1 day...Can we connect with teamviewer..plz???

Comment: It is not possible to save submissions from two different users into a single session if that is what you are trying to achieve. If it is the same user in a multi-step form then it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass like this and when submitting form get the value by

input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="names[]"  value="$value2['package_title']">

input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="names[]" value="$value['mrp']">

input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="names[]" value="$total"/>

$name=$_POST['names']; 
$answer = implode($name, ",");

then assign the name value to a session.

$_SEESION['name']=$answer;

Comment: Thank you for reply...But I tried it from 1 day...Can we connect with teamviewer..plz???

Comment: I have updated my comments. Please check it. I canoot connect through team viewer.